# Interact with Facebook data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, facebook-like

I would like to know if there is a way to extract some informations from facebook users and pages without creating a facebook app.
In other words, I would like to know if it is possible to do on facebook what can be done on Twitter using their streaming API (facebook is more suitable for my purposes), or if is there a dataset that I can query without having to interact with every single user to get his/her permission (without using access tokens).
To be more specific, I need to know two kind of infos from users: the place where they live and their likes on page and nothing more, users can be anonymous or with a fake ID or whatever.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For privacy reasons, it is not possible at all. You must authorize a user with the correct permissions to get that kind of data.

Also, you would not be allowed to use the data in any way without asking the user for permission, and scraping is not allowed on Facebook. Even if it would be possible without the Graph API, it would not be allowed.